# WPF VS2013 - add new Window to project as child of main Window

Tags: wpf, window, children, mdi

I'm trying to switch from WinForms to WPF in my C# app. My WinForms app is MDI app. I need to make it also MDI in WPF. How can I lock new window to my app mainwindow or canvas on that window? My child window cannot get outside of app main window. This child window have to be shown on click event of menu item of main window.

Comment: Show some screenshot

Comment: Take a look at [WPF Multiple Document Interface (MDI)](http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex.

Answer (score -1):

In your situation the best solution is to use System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost control. This contol allows you put any WPF control that you like. Follow these steps:
1) In Windows Forms project create child form
2) Inside this form add System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost control
3) in code behind do smomething like this:

```
wpfElementHost.Child = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock()
        {
            Text = "Hello from WPF world.",
            FontSize = 25,
            FontStyle = System.Windows.FontStyles.Italic,
            FontWeight = System.Windows.FontWeights.Bold,
            TextAlignment = System.Windows.TextAlignment.Center
        };
```

Note I used fully qualified name because Windows Forms and WPF have many in common. In my case wpfElementHost is System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost. You can host any control, e.g. just create custom control or user control as class a library and use them in windows forms application.
Hope this helped. Let me know if I correctly answered your question.

Comment: Unfortunately we misunderstood :( I'm not writing WinForms apps but WPF and I need some WinForms functionalities - the main one is to create in WPF new item Window and set it to child of main window and configure that it cannot get out of that main window.